# Uploading the logs from the VM instance to the Azure Storage Account fails for .NET Memory Allocation (Sampling) with Azure Tools August 2011 1.4

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, memory, azure, allocation

I am trying to use the new Visual Studio 2010 Azure Toolkit August 2011 update Profiling feature to collect .NET Memory Allocation reports of my Worker roles to diagnose memory leak issues, but when I choose "View Profiling Report" from the Server Explorer, which initiates the "Uploading the logs from the VM instance to the Windows Azure storage account" process, I eventually receive a, "Profiling log request failed. Details: The Profiling agent did not respond in a timely fashion' response.

Frankly, I could care less if it took all day, I just want to see the memory profile report. Any ideas on how to make this work or what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: After a week of trying, a request for profiling logs went through, and the file was successfully downloaded. Unlike CPU Sampling reports, which tend to be between 200-800 Mb, this report was 4.2 Gb, which probably explains what the trouble was. Nonetheless, it would be great to know (1) what these limitations are, and (2) if there's a way for me to constrain my memory allocation analysis with these tools to prevent such a large report from being generated, increasing the likelihood of successful log transfers.

Comment: Could you just use Azure Diagnostics to monitor the correct performance counter(s) and tell it to push to storage in smaller chunks?  Then maybe it wouldn't be so huge.

Comment: Yes. Partly, I was interested in figuring out how useful what visual studio did for me was, but you're right, figuring out the right performance counters is the best way to go.